# AJ-SR04M Screw Purpose

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I've got 3 AJ-SR04M sensors working on an Arduino MKR Wifi 1010, but I was curious what the purpose of this screw on the sensor boards is. It seems to somehow impact the accuracy/performance, but I can't seem to find any info on it. Anyone know what this is called/what it does exactly?

[image]

Comment: Adjustable inductor

Comment: could be a selector switch

Comment: @jsotola No, it's an adjustable inductor. You get them by the hundred in old radios. The black thing in the middle is a ferrite core that screws in and out to change the inductance. You need a special plastic screwdriver to adjust them so that the metal of the screwdriver doesn't affect the inductance while you're tuning it.

Comment: The purpose is probably to tune a bandpass filter. At a guess.

Comment: As @Majenko says, it's probably for inductor tuning. Since it's not mentioned in the documentation, I would suppose it may already be tuned or adjusted at the factory during final test. That's not the say you can't tinker with it, but as you noted, it requires a little more detail on what it exactly does to do that.

Comment: @Majenko thank you! Luckily I only fiddle with one of 3 that I bought so I'm just going to try to tune it back to look like the other 2.